# jQuery.closest() gives "null" value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-tooltip

I am doing with this [plugin](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/) :

```
<table>
<tr>
     <td>
     <a class="linkType1" href="google.com">
         Google
     </a>
     <span style="display: none;">Goooooooooooogle</span>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
    <a class="linkType1" href="yahoo.com">
        Yahoo
    </a>
    <span style="display: none;">Yaaaaaaaaaaaaaaho</span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can I select the `closest` `span` of `linkType1`-anchors for displaying as tooltip ?

Currently I am doing :

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery("a.linkType1").tooltip({ 
        bodyHandler: function() { 
            alert(jQuery(this).closest("span").html()); // this alert is showing `null`
            return "hi"; // i need to setup the alerted content here
        }, 
        showURL: false 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `span` elements aren't ancestors of the links, so `closest` (which looks for a match for the selector on the current element or its ancestors) isn't what you're looking for.

Based on your markup, you might want [`next("span")`](http://api.jquery.com/next) (which will find the next sibling, but only if it's a span; it doesn't continue with subsequent siblings) or possibly `nextAll("span").first()` (which will find the first next sibling that's a span, in case you ever put something between the `a` and the `span`), which finds all subsequent siblings with [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll) and then grabs the first of them (the one nearest the link) via [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first). So

```
// If the `span` will always be the very next sibling
alert(jQuery(this).next("span").html());
```

or

```
// If you may put something between the `a` and the `span` at some point
alert(jQuery(this).nextAll("span").first().html());
```

Comment: i think too much vote up... will accept this after 7 minutes. Thanks T.J, thats exactly what I need. +1

Comment: could you please look into my another problem ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8937158/778687

Answer (score 2):

`closest()` finds the closest **parent** element. You are looking for a sibling:

```
jQuery(this).next("span").html()
```

Comment: According to the API: Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

Comment: Parent element or **current** element (if it matches the selector).

Comment: +1 could you please look into my another problem ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8937158/778687

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` is referring to bodyHandler function.
Try this

```
alert(jQuery(linkType1).closest("span").html());
```

Why not use `find()` instead? As closest() transverses up the `DOM` tree

Comment: *"`$(this)` is referring to bodyHandler function"* No, it isn't. The body handler function is called with `this` set to the DOM element (the plug-in, like most, is consistent with how jQuery works).